# Elasticsearch not_analyzed field is not searchable

Tags: elasticsearch

Good day!

I am running elasticsearch 5.0 version. I've added not_analyzed field, but it's not searchable. Index was created in previous elasticsearch version - 2.4.

http://es.domain.com:9200/log-2016.11.04/app/_mapping?pretty shows me the following:

```
      "app" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "fielddata" : false
          },
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "fielddata" : false
          }
        },
        "fielddata" : false
      },

.... skipped ...

      "event" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256,
            "fielddata" : false
          },
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "fielddata" : false
          }
        },
        "fielddata" : false
      },
```

So, when i am trying to search by app.raw (or app.keyword) - it shows me results:

```
http://es.domain.com:9200/log-2016.11.04/app/_search?q=app.keyword:value1&pretty

    {
  "took" : 356,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 974120,
    "max_score" : 3.0174136,
```

But when i am trying to search by event.keyword it shows me nothing:

```
http://es.domain.com:9200/log-2016.11.04/app/_search?q=event.keyword:value&pretty
```

Results:

```
    {
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

This fields were added using elasticsearch api:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/log-2016.11.04/app/_mappings -d @field.json
```

field.json:

```
{
"properties": {
        "event": {
                "type": "string",
                "fielddata": false,
                "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                }
        }
}
}
```

Can somebody help me with it?

Thanks!

Comment: If that field was added after you indexed the documents, then what you get is the expected result.

Comment: @AndreiStefan both fields were added after index was indexed. But i can search by app.keyword, but can't by event.keyword.

Comment: What do you mean by "after index was indexed"? Maybe you wanted to say "after documents were indexed"?

Comment: @AndreiStefan yep, sorry. I meant "after documents were indexed".

Comment: Then it's impossible that first query runs. None of them should return anything as they will have no value. Adding a field to an index **after** the documents have been indexed will not auto-magically populate those fields.